# Obtaining the Solar Gun in Metal Gear Solid 4

Tags: metal-gear-solid-4-guns-of-patriots

To get it you must collect all the dolls by killing bosses by nonlethal means. Do I have to collect them in a single run or do dolls collected in previous runs count too?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They carry over between runs, and I believe you can view them in Sunny's kitchen.

Comment: How do I access Sunny's kitchen? Or I have to look for them on cutscenes?

Answer (score 1):

In answer to David McDavidson's follow-up question, in the Mission Briefings you are able to take control (prompts on-screen) of the Mk.II/III and navigate around the ship.

Simply travel upstairs (by pushing against the bottom step - Mk.II will automatically fly up) and in the kitchen, opposite where Sunny cooks her eggs, you'll see a bench. All dolls collected will be sat on the bench.